# Couchbase named parameters for buckets

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, couchbase

I'm trying to add a named parameter to fill in for my bucket name but I'm unable to get it working.

```
  var query = new QueryRequest()
    .Statement("SELECT b.*, META(b).id FROM $bucketName b WHERE b.type = 'Board' AND b.environment = $environment")
                .AddNamedParameter("$bucketName", _bucketName)
                .AddNamedParameter("$environment", _environment);

  query.ScanConsistency(ScanConsistency.RequestPlus);

  var result = _bucket.Query<Board>(query);
```

The following works correctly:

```
  var query = new QueryRequest()
    .Statement("SELECT b.*, META(b).id FROM `travel-sample` b WHERE b.type = 'Board' AND b.environment = $environment")
                .AddNamedParameter("$environment", _environment);
```

EDIT: this also doesn't work

```
.AddNamedParameter("$bucketName", $"`{_bucketName}`")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use a parameter for bucket name (happy to be proven wrong). What I've done in these scenarios is use the bucket object itself to get the name. Like:

```
var n1ql = $"SELECT t.* FROM `{_bucket.Name}` t LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid this if possible - but if it works... it works :) I'll leave it open for a bit to see if anyone else can provide some insight. I cross posted this on the couchbase forums too.

Comment: I asked in the couchbase-sdk gitter channel for others to take a look, but it's late on a Friday so don't hold your breath :) Best to keep it open for a few days, hopefully someone has a better answer than me https://gitter.im/couchbase/couchbase-dotnet-sdk

Comment: Matthew is correct that this is generally not possible.  Specifically, paths cannot be parameterized, but values can.  This was discussed recently at https://forums.couchbase.com/t/java-implementation-of-n1qlquery-parameterized-query-json-object/19853/4

Comment: Mathew, Matt are right. bucket name in the FROM CLAUSE must be Identifier and Identifier’s can’t be parametrized. As Mathew suggested you can dynamically generate statement.